# Matrix Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given three planes:

$$x + y + 6z = 4$$

$$x + 2y + 8z = 7$$

$$2x + 4y + 16z = 15$$

The question first asked to convert these into a coefficient matrix. Secondly it asked me to use Gaussian elimination to solve the matrix equation. The solution i got was $(2, 11/4, 1/8)$. The third part is where i get confused. it asks me to write down the matrix that produces the first row operation in my solution to part b. What is this question asking me to do.?

Comment: Can you reference your question?

Comment: Performing an elementary row operation is equivalent to left-multiplying by some nonsingular matrix. You are asked to find the matrix that corresponds to whatever the first step was when you performed the Gaussian elimination.

Comment: The system in the question does not have the given solution (  note that the last two equations are not compatible).